# How to add user defined jar in wildfly server

Tags: wildfly-8

I am new to wildfly8.1 sever. In my application ear, I have a dependency to `interfaces.jar`, so how can i add in wildfly server?

Answer (score 1):

The lib/ext doesn't work anymore in JB8 (wildfly). You need to create - wtf - a module now! Look at the docs in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Answer (score 0):

Put it in folder **wildfly/8.1.0.Final/standalone/lib/ext**

Comment: thanks for your reply, Hi i placed my interfaces.jar into D:\Servers\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\standalone\lib\ext . But the i getting class not found error                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nexge/ruleengine/dataservices/BillingDO

Comment: then you need to add it's further dependencies.